# What happens to the potential energy of an object if the conservative force associated with it vanishes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

Now, some textbooks have been telling me that when you do work against a conservative force, ("it is stored up as potential energy") Apparently this gives the ability to do work, because when the force doing the work disappears, the conservative force acting on the object can do work on the object that converts this P.E. into K.E. Now, my question is that after the applied force has done work against the conservative force, and the source of the conservative force disappears, the potential energy stored up in the object really can do no work. So how can I harness this energy? It will be practically useless without the force field. So the conservative force shouldn't disappear, but what in the definition of  conservative force prevents it from disappearing please explain fully. I feel like this has to do with the fact that unlike other forms of energy,P.E. isn't defined without its conservative force field. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct: If you lift a mass $m$ to the height $h$ above the ground against the gravitational force, you have done the work $W = F h = m g h$. Thus, this energy is stored in the body as potential energy. Now, **if** one could switch of gravity, the potential energy would be lost. Unfortunately, one can't.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, mathematically speaking there's nothing wrong with making a vector field vary in time. And in fact gravity does do this in the real world, with massive objects moving around. However, if you had one planet producing a gravitational field, and it just disappeared, that gravitational field would not be conservative. To be conservative, change in energy must be path independent, which includes time, and if the field turned off, it would matter when a particle was at each point of its trajectory.

Comment: I really think this is a good question, it got me thinking of something I'd taken for granted. Both the comments above are pretty useful too...

Comment: @Liam Clink can you please elaborate? I understand that you are hinting at the fact that if the gravitational field could be turned off, gravity wouldn't be a conservative force.

Comment: Please reopen it. I have edited this again, according to suggestions